# two network from one adsl connection,

Tags: vpn, router, adsl

If i use a telephone splitter at an adsl line and connect a VPN test modem and the existing modem to the output of the line splitter,can i get two network with different static ip address? I know this is not a best practice as it can results in collisions. But i need to check a VPN modem/router before sending this to a remote branch? So if i can create a different static ip adress on the VPN modem, i can connect few computers to this modem and establish VPN channels to the exsiting modem. Will this setup work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it will not work. DSL lines require a dedicated copper pair from the modem back to the port in the CO DSLAM.

Comment: damn you're fast!

Comment: And that was typed on my phone. :)

Answer (score 2):

DSL is not a collision-detect system where you can just connect arbitrary nodes.  It is a point to point link on which one DSLAM and one modem exists.  In other words, you can never attach more than one modem (or DSLAM) to a single ADSL circuit; you'd need your ISP to provision another physical circuit.